# How to solve an inhibited alert still alerting due to race condition

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager, victoriametrics

I currently am running into an issue where I have two alerts where one will always fire if the other is also firing.

First Alert (ServerOffline): Detects based on a ping exporter if a server has gone offline. This alert is setup to query every 1s and generally will fire within 2-3 minutes of actual loss of ping.
`sum(ping_loss_ratio >= .7) by (instance, instance_region) >= 2`

Second Alert (NoVectorData): Detects if my metrics have stopped flowing from the servers. This alert is setup to track a range of 12h worth of data and if it stops flowing for 15min, my alerting system will fire an alert if that condition is true after 10 minutes. This will take roughly 30~ mins to fire due to the group_wait that is setup for this alert.
`count by (instance, instance_region)(lag(vector_component_sent_events_total{component_id="vector_sink"}[12h]) > 15m) >= 1`

I have a simple inhibition rule setup that works just fine for preventing the NoVectorData alert from being sent if a server is marked offline.

```
inhibit_rules:
  - source_matchers: [alertname="ServerOffline"]
    target_matchers: [alertname="NoVectorData"]
    equal: ['instance']
```

The problem with this is if the server was offline for more than the 30min, but comes back up it recovers the ServerOffline alert faster than it recovers the NoVectorData alert. This will then make the NoVectorData alert fire as the silence that the inhibit rules setup would no longer be active. I am struggling to find a proper solution to add some sort of buffer to prevent this. Here is my current route settings for these alerts.

```
   - matchers:
        - alertname="ServerOffline"
      group_by: ['alertname', 'instance_region']
      receiver: 'slack.hook.resolve'
      group_wait: 30s
      repeat_interval: 24h
    - matchers:
        - alertname="NoVectorData"
      group_by: ['alertname', 'instance_region']
      group_wait: 5m
      repeat_interval: 1h
```

I can provide any further details on the setup if needed.

Comment: Your alert rule looks somewhat strange (first one). Can you explain in more details what is `ping_loss_ratio` and what expression of that rule calculates exactly?

Comment: @markalex This query checks the value that each of the 4 ping exporters I set up returns for each specific server. It should trigger the alert if it reaches over 70% loss from 2 of the 4 exporters. 

The ping exporters get scrapped every 15 seconds.

Comment: This is some kind of self made exporter? How ping_loss_ratio is calculated? Also what you described doesn't corespond to what is written in query: it would be true if you use count instead of sum.

Comment: Have you considered using expression `count(ping_loss_ratio >= .7) by (instance, instance_region) >= 2<4`? So that alert is not triggered at all if **all** services are down? Also, why are you not using blackbox exporter?

Comment: This is the ping exporter in use: https://github.com/czerwonk/ping_exporter/tree/1.1.0
It produces a value of 0.0-1.0 to provide a percentage of loss.
I would want it to alert if all 4 are reporting, and in my circumstance, we have leeway to assume that if 2 of the exporters are reporting upwards of 70% loss then the service is down regardless. This was an attempt to speed up the reporting of downed servers. The query works just fine and I dont see how that would correlate to how fast the NoVectorData alert takes to resolve.
Never considered BB exporter. How would that be beneficial?

Comment: Blackbox exporter allows to tinker with how you define server is down (in terms of time windows and such). I'm not familiar with mentioned exporter, but based on very quick glance - it's probably OK. Regarding you issue, I guess the only way is to abandon inhibition and incorporate filter in your rules. I'd try something like this: `sum(ping_loss_ratio >= .7) by (instance, instance_region) >= 2 unless on(instance, instance_region) last_over_time(ALERTS{alertname="NoVectorData", alertstate="firing"} [5m])` (adjust last range selector according to your needs)

Comment: Sadly I don't have any sort of metrics from VMalert that could help me accomplish conditional querying like that.  There are some metrics it provides about the specific alerts but they are just cumulative values of how many of each specific alert is firing. There is an alerts endpoint but its format would not be scrapable it seems.

Comment: Guy from VM are quite active here, so they might help with this. In the mean time you can use second alert expression instead of `ALERTS` metric (with a couple more parenthesis and range selector like `[5m:]` to invoke [subquery syntax](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery)).